# What is the meaning of col2=b1(1:end,lead) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I would like to know what the meaning of

```
col2=b1(1:end,lead);
```

is in MATLAB?

Comment: Check [Matrix Indexing in Matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic stuff. We are led to assume that `b1` is a 2-dimensional array. The contents of an array are indexed using brackets, so `b1(1,1)` will return the top left element of array `b1`. The first index in your example, `1:end` is selecting every element in the first dimension (matlab indexes rows first, then columns). The second index, `lead` in your example, selects a particular column. We assume that `lead` has been allocated previously somewhere in the code.

Thence, `b1(1:end,lead)` returns to `col2` a 1-dimensional array containing a subarray of `b1`. This could be accomplished more elegantly using `col2=b1(:,lead);`.